# Does Telegram API let to get photo from camera?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need bot which let to send it command ('/photo' for example) and in return get photo from camera. Does Telegram API let to do it?

Answer (score 1):

as you can check in the [official documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#keyboardbutton), you can only request for his phone number or his location. and it is not possible to request for camera input. but you can request your user to manually take a photo and send to your bot.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Telegram API does not allow you to directly access a user's camera. This is for security and privacy reasons.